# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver xx.xx.ImediateSMSReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception, receiver

I looked around for this question first before this post and figured I am not getting an answer that applies to me. So here I go :

I am developing an Android App which should receive SMS messages and uses the SMSes to do various things. The app is working fine in General, however each time a user closes the App or Reboots their phone and receive a relevant SMS before opening the app, it crashes giving a message "Unfortunately, Appname has stopped". Please help - below is my Receiver Class, Logcat and a Portion of my Manifest File.

PREFS CLASS

```
public class Prefs {

    static Prefs singleton = null;

    static SharedPreferences preferences;

    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    Prefs(Context context) {
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    Prefs(Context context, String name, int mode) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public static Prefs with(Context context) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Builder(context, null, -1).build();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public static Prefs with(Context context, String name, int mode) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Builder(context, name, mode).build();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public void save(String key, boolean value) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    public void save(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    public void save(String key, int value) {
        editor.putInt(key, value).apply();
    }

    public void save(String key, float value) {
        editor.putFloat(key, value).apply();
    }

    public void save(String key, long value) {
        editor.putLong(key, value).apply();
    }

    public void save(String key, Set<String> value) {
        editor.putStringSet(key, value).apply();
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }

    public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
        return preferences.getString(key, defValue);
    }

    public int getInt(String key, int defValue) {
        return preferences.getInt(key, defValue);
    }

    public float getFloat(String key, float defValue) {
        return preferences.getFloat(key, defValue);
    }

    public long getLong(String key, long defValue) {
        return preferences.getLong(key, defValue);
    }

    public Set<String> getStringSet(String key, Set<String> defValue) {
        return preferences.getStringSet(key, defValue);
    }

    public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
        return preferences.getAll();
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        editor.remove(key).apply();
    }

    public void removeAll(){
        editor.clear().apply();
    }

    public void contains(String key){
        preferences.contains(key);
    }

    private static class Builder {

        private final Context context;
        private final int mode;
        private final String name;

        public Builder(Context context, String name, int mode) {
            if (context == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
            }
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
            this.name = name;
            this.mode = mode;
        }

        /**
        * Method that creates an instance of Prefs
        *
        * @return an instance of Prefs
        */
        public Prefs build() {
            if (mode == -1 || name == null) {
                return new Prefs(context);
            }
            return new Prefs(context, name, mode);
        }
    }
}
```

SMS RECEIVER CLASS

```
public class ImediateSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = ImediateSMSReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    String amount = "";
    String merch = "";
    String ref = "";
    String date = "";
    String time = "";
    String account = "";
    String balance = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Running onReceive from " + TAG);

        if (intent.hasExtra("pdus")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (messages != null && !messages.equals("")) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "Current Number of Messages Length " + messages.length);

                TemplateReader reader = new TemplateReader(context);
                String message = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();

                long id = reader.read(message, new Date());
                if (id != 0) {
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
                    notificationManager.SendTransactionNotification(context, (int) id,
                            TransactionFragment.class.getName(), message);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Message is " + messages);

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Message is NULL");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
10-29 12:11:24.747: D/AssetManager(25433): addAssetPath path =/data/app/xx.xx.appname-1/base.apkmapset is 0
10-29 12:11:24.747: D/AssetManager(25433): addAssetPath path =/data/app/xx.xx.appname-1/base.apk, mapOffset =0
10-29 12:11:24.747: D/AssetManager(25433): addAssetPath path =/data/app/xx.xx.appname-1/base.apk,elasticAppCookieOffset ={3=0}
10-29 12:11:24.837: D/InjectionManager(25433): fillFeatureStoreMap xx.xx.appname
10-29 12:11:24.837: I/InjectionManager(25433): Constructor xx.xx.appname, Feature store :{}
10-29 12:11:24.837: I/LoadedApk(25433): getClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xx.xx.appname/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433): Process: xx.xx.appname, PID: 25433
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver xx.xx.appname.util.ImediateSMSReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.xtras.Prefs$Builder.<init>(Prefs.java:115)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.xtras.Prefs.with(Prefs.java:31)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.util.TemplateReader.createAccountInDB(TemplateReader.java:676)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.util.TemplateReader.createTransactionInDB(TemplateReader.java:522)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.util.TemplateReader.createTransaction(TemplateReader.java:500)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.util.TemplateReader.read(TemplateReader.java:441)
10-29 12:11:24.887: E/AndroidRuntime(25433):    at xx.xx.appname.util.ImediateSMSReceiver.onReceive(ImediateSMSReceiver.java:56)
```

MANIFEST

```
<receiver
android:name=".util.ImediateSMSReceiver"
android:enabled="true" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 115 of Prefs.java is attempting to use a context object that has not been initialised.Seems to be in an inner class called `Builder`

The code posted is not really relevant as the problem lies is code somewhere in TemplateReader or Prefs where you appear to be using the wrong context (using a null context instead of one that is passed in)

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for the Pointer. The problem lies in my TemplateReader Class.. I am trying to use a string which is supposed to be stored by my Prefs file but ts not yet there hence returning null... Thanks.